# Opening target symbolic link for mismatched file

Tags: c, winapi, symlink, createfile

I’ve seen some related questions but failed to find the exact solution for my problem…

Anyway, I have an invalid symlink made like this:

```
mklink link path/to/dir
```

Meaning I’m linking to a directory **without the /D flag**.

However, when I try to open the target file using the WinApi `CreateFile` it fails. Do I need to open the symlink as a file or as a directory?

```
CreateFile(path_to_link, 
0,
0,
NULL,
OPEN_EXISTING,
[*],
NULL)
```

When I specify a directory at [*] the function fails (Access Denied by GetLastError(). I believe that’s because the path itself configured as a file, since I have valid permission to all relevant files).

What do I need to put at [*] to handle `path/to/dir` ?

Notes:

- I must handle this kind of invalid use of mklink
- My final goal is to get the absolute path of `path/to/dir`. If there is another way without `CreateFile` I’d love to hear about it:)

Comment: "*My final goal is to get the absolute path of `path/to/dir.`*" - see [How to find target of symbolic link in Windows C++ program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23621778/)

Answer (score 1):

A ***file*** symbolic link which links to a ***directory*** cannot cooperate with ***CreateFile***.

By default, [mklink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink) creates a file symbolic link. And according to [Symbolic Link Effects on File Systems Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/symbolic-link-effects-on-file-systems-functions#createfile-and-createfiletransacted), for **CreateFile and CreateFileTransacted**,

**If FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT is specified and:**

- If an existing file is opened and it is a symbolic link, the handle
  returned is a handle to the symbolic link.
- If CREATE_ALWAYS, TRUNCATE_EXISTING, or FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE are
  specified, the file affected is a symbolic link.

**If FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT is not specified and:**

- If an existing file is opened and it is a symbolic link, the handle
  returned is a handle to the target.
- If CREATE_ALWAYS, TRUNCATE_EXISTING, or FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE are
  specified, the file affected is the target.

And [A *hard link* is the file system representation of a **file** by which more than one path references a single file in the **same** volume.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/hard-links-and-junctions#hard-links)

The following code which reads a directory symbolic link works for me.

```
HANDLE h =CreateFile(L"C:\\Users\\SymbolicLink\\To\\MyFolder", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ,NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comment, it behaves like a [Shell Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23621778/how-to-find-target-of-symbolic-link-in-windows-c-program). Here is one way to resolve the target path, it uses the [IShellItem2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ishellitem) COM interface and the [System.Link.TargetParsingPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/props-system-link-targetparsingpath) property.

C++ version:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <shobjidl_core.h>
#include <Propkey.h>

int main()
{
  CoInitialize(NULL);
  {
    IShellItem2* item;
    if (SUCCEEDED(SHCreateItemFromParsingName(L"c:\\mypath\\link", NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&item))))
    {
      LPWSTR path = NULL;
      if (SUCCEEDED(item->GetString(PKEY_Link_TargetParsingPath, &path)))
      {
        wprintf(L"Target: %s\n", path); // x:\path\to\dir
        CoTaskMemFree(name);
      }
      item->Release();
    }
  }
  CoUninitialize();
  return 0;
}
```

C version:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <shobjidl_core.h>
#include <Propkey.h>

int main()
{
  CoInitialize(NULL);
  {
    IShellItem2* item;
    if (SUCCEEDED(SHCreateItemFromParsingName(L"c:\\mypath\\link", NULL, &IID_IShellItem2, &item)))
    {
      LPWSTR path = NULL;
      if (SUCCEEDED(item->lpVtbl->GetString(item, &PKEY_Link_TargetParsingPath, &path)))
      {
        wprintf(L"Target: %s\n", path); // x:\path\to\dir
        CoTaskMemFree(path);
      }

      item->lpVtbl->Release(item);
    }
  }
  CoUninitialize();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't [`mklink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink) create an actual symbolic/hard link as opposed to a shell link file?

Comment: @IInspectable - In fact, I'm not 100% sure about symbolic vs shell link file. There are indeed different - It's not a Shell link file (.lnk) - but it behaves the same in terms of resolution (IShellLink, etc.). I've made an update in that sense.

Comment: Sounds cool, I'll try it later :). But from a brief view, it looks like a c++ solution. If so, do you happen to know any c alternative?

Comment: @DnielBV - I have added the C version